# Call a simple function from a button in ASP.NET Core (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been looking really hard to answer what I thought would be such a simple question, but how do I call a function from the Controller of a page using an HTML form/button.

*The end-goal here is to make an add-to-cart button, but I must firstly figure out how to make a button in the first place.*

---

This is the most common method I saw people doing:

The function in my controller I want to run is as such:
[image: Function]

and then in my `Index.cshtml` file I have this block of code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Index", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test" />
}
```

and the button shows up as it should,

[image: Button]

but when I press it...

[image: Button]

It just redirects to a page with the name of the function i'm trying to call instead of actually running it. I clearly have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the buttons work, but this is the answer I keep finding online.

Comment: You mean the code `Debug.Write` is not executing? Did you try to debug? Do you have a view with name PostTest ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya correct, the output never arrives  in the console. And no I have no view with that name, just the function. Do I need a view for every function ?

Comment: I think I can see the real issue now.. `Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Index"` should have`Smoothies` instead of `Index`. And yes, since you're are doing `return View()` it will try to load view with the same name as controller action. So you need to have view with the same name as action name. Or you can return some tiger view by specifying name in View(). Example `return View("some view");`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ah Yes! Now it's getting somewhere. Thank you for the assistance it's a good bit clearer now. I think I can finish it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is wrong. It should be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Smoothies", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL, It seems wrong.

Your URL will be "ControllerName/Methodname".

in your case it will "Smothies/PostTest"